# Notebook keyboard sending wrong or multiple keys at once

Tags: keyboard

My Inspiron 14R 5420 notebook which is currently running Windows 7 Home Basic x64 sometimes (mostly when I restart the pc) it starts to bug the keyboard, I will give an example of the inputs and outputs below:

```
Input: 'g' or 't', output: 'gt' 
Input: 'h' or 'y', output: 'hy' 
Input: CAPS Lock, output: CAPS Lock and '\' 
Input: Alt+tab, output: Win Key 
Input: Shift+Letter Key, output: Error beep 
Input: Backspace, output: Delete latest written character (in a text form), and always send a BACK command, like back to the last page in internet browsers, windows explorer, etc..
```

Some few other keys have wrong output as well but I don't remember which.

The thing is also that after a while that the computer is doing this, it start to work as if all of this didn't happen.

Someone might know a solution to my problem? I really can't say if its Hardware or Software malfunction if it is software i'll try formatting my system soon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spill anything in it?

Comment: Nothing, I use the notebook carefuly.

Comment: Try it with a LiveCD (or alike), if it's still doing it, then it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a VIRUS I got, actually the first one, after a while with the virus McAfee updated its virus database information and were able to detect it.
Once I found out it was a virus i formatted my PC and its all working great now.